# How to Topologically Sort a Directed Graph with Cycles

Tags: d3.js, graph, graph-theory, topological-sort

I'm struggling to define this problem exactly, which is part of the reason I cannot solve it. Basically, I want to assign numbers to nodes that provides a kind of topological sorting, but if there is a cycle in the graph, which I want to allow, it should assign values to the nodes that essentially count up the distance from nearest non-cycle nodes.[image]

eg, If there were another non-cyclic dependency, the numbers assigned to the nodes may look more like this.

[image]

Currently, the numbers assigned are just based on total dependencies, which creates less-than-ideal layouts.

[image]

I have a feeling that I might need to use some algorithm involving Strongly Connected Components, but I'm not sure how to apply it to get the desired result. Any help clarifying this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not very clear what is the desired result. "topologically" means something else in my textbook. Do you mean some sort of desired 'x' position in the drawing of the graph?

Comment: Basically, yes. I was just using the definition of topological sort I found on Wikipedia, which requires an acyclic graph, or a graph broken into SCCs

Answer (score 2):

[Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) for generating Strongly Connected Components already topologically sorts the components (in reverse). On the other hand, [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) gives you the shortest path to a given node in a graph.

So the approach I went with was:

1. implementing Tarjan's algorithm to sort all SCCs
2. applying Bellman-Ford to any SCCs of more than one node, where the shortest path is calculated to an arbitrarily-selected "entry node", ie, a node with a predecessor leading outside the cycle.

which renders graphs like this:
[image]

not too bad!

Answer (score 0):

Well, just a general idea: I would try to find the longest possible shortest path (I mean, `max( shortest_path(node1, node2) for node1 in nodes, node2 in nodes)`. So "longest shortest" is not an oxymoron here), in the undirected graph (so ignoring arrows).

And I would chose index along that longest path.

And then, for all other nodes, you have to choose (arbitrarily) between `index of closest node with index`, `index of closest node with index - distance` or `index of closest node with index + distance`.